# Can we use two buffered writers to write on the same file with java, in the same class?

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedwriter, writer

I have been wondering if I cam use two bufferedWriters to write an external file with java.
This is what I did:

But there is only written X in my created file, any ideas ? 
It seems like the file gets formatted once the second writer starts working.

```
public void declareVariables() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {

            bufferedWriter.write("Y");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        bufferedWriter.flush();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                }
}


public void affectVariables() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {

            bufferedWriter.write("X");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the javadoc for FileWriter. You can use that class to append to existing files, or to overwrite existing content....

Comment: Oh yes ! thank you so much !!

Comment: @markspace yes, he does: he's using a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Also note : the real question is : why don't you just first compile all required content, and then write all of that into the file in one shot?!

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner to write every part at once.. ? @GhostCat

Comment: Other than that i found a simple solution by searching a bit in the javadoc FileWriter, I had to instanciate The file Writer with another constructor where i specify if i want it to append the existing document or not via a second (boolean) parameter! 
Thank you all !

Comment: @JBNizet Ah right, sorry missed that.

Answer (score 0):

to write in a file you have to use FileWriter like this:

```
public void declareVariables() {
    try {

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"), true);
        writer.append("X");
        //try with resources block calls the close method upon exit and which implicitly calls the flush method. 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void affectVariables()  {
    try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"), true);
            writer.append("X");
            //try with resources block calls the close method upon exit and which implicitly calls the flush method. 
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You do not need to put close() and flush() because try with resources block calls the close method upon exit and which implicitly calls the flush method.
doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()